# creating java library jars with intellij

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a library jar out of the compiled java files or a piece of code organized into directories. When I create the jar file using eclipse and use it in the actual code it is working fine but when i use intellij to create the jar file, the code is not able to find the packages which are in the jar file. when i compare the two jar files(the one created by eclipse and the one created by intellij), they have the same directory structure and both have manifest files with dummy information. What could i be doing wrong here. I think i am missing something obvious.

Thanks

edit: The question is answered, I need to put the 'compiled output' into the jar ; i was manually adding the compiled class files to jar and for some reason it did not work.

Comment: Is the JAR being used by a different project or are you talking about two modules in the same project?

Comment: @NBW there is a base code upon which we build the actual application. The base code just provides with utilities we use in the actual code. And we use the base code in the actual code in form of a jar library file.

Comment: @salsalsabear OK - now is this base code part of the project (eg. a source path) that you wish to use it in the from of the JAR or is this JAR built seperately from this project and you reference it (via Maven or file system location etc)? It sounds like the former but I am just trying to clarify so I can give you the correct advice. Thanks.

Comment: @NBW This jar file is built from base code totally seperately and we import this jar file in our actual project; Hope that provides clarification

Comment: So you're compiling your source code into two distinct jar files?

Answer (score 7):

You can use artifacts to achieve this: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/ and http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/packaging-a-module-into-a-jar-file.html. This is the way you do it in intellij.